# How to add and modify new sections in the dropdown menu (CHROMIUM SOURCE CODE)?

Tags: c++, chromium

I need to add new sections to the dropdown menu at the right on the top of the chromium browser, how can i create new sections that popping up after i click on them and they open in another tab like chrome://settings , chrome://about ecc. , and how can i modify the page inside of it  ?

Looking foward, 
Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad topic. You should modify this file: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/app/generated_resources.grd?q=%22New+incognito+window%22&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=879 to add a new menu item. Those Chrome URLs are generally html and javascript files and are located here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/

Comment: really helpful, so basically i should add a new </message> string for any section i need to add, then create a new .htlm file for each chrome url, link them , after that upload the changes to Build.gn, right?

Comment: You will have to do more than that. Just search for one of the name tags on their site and look at the references. Like I said it's a very broad topic and can't be covered here.